# Access nested route of child page from the Root component

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to enable nesting routes on `BarcodeScannerComponent` component. I have tried like below. But it is not working. The problem here is how to access the nested route within the root component. i.e. `app.component.ts`. Because my navigation button is on the `HeaderComponent`. Any clue here?

I can do this task without having nesting routes. But then my dashboard component destroys when the user moves to the barcode page. So I need to avoid that. That is why I have decided to go with the Nesting route pattern here.

*app.component.ts*

```
<div>

    <app-header> </app-header>

    <main>
        <router-outlet> </router-outlet>
    </main>
    
</div>
```

*header.componet.html*

```
<p-menubar>

   <i (click)="goToBarcodeScannerPage()"></i>

</p-menubar>
```

*header.componet.ts*

```
goToBarcodeScannerPage(): void {
   this.router.navigateByUrl('barcode-scanner'); // This is not working
 }
```

*dasboard.componet.html*

```
// removed other HTML

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

*dashboard-routing.module.ts*

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'barcode-scanner',
        component: BarcodeScannerComponent
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

*app-routing.module.ts*

```
const routes: Routes = [
  
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule),
    ...canActivate(redirectUnauthorizedToLogin)
  },
  
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
goToBarcodeScannerPage(): void {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard/barcode-scanner');
}
```

You need to use the absolute path and it can be done by adding slash (`/`) in front of the url.

And now on your code, `dashboard` component has `<router-outlet>` and `barcode` component will be loaded inside that tag so to hide the `dashboard` component html code when showing the `barcode` component html content, it is needed to create new component that contains the `dashboard` component html content and make a route for that as follows.

```
// Create new component `DashboardMainComponent` that contains `Dashboard` component html content
```

On **dashboard-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: DashboardMainComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'barcode-scanner',
        component: BarcodeScannerComponent
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: ''
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

Comment: No. It goes to a page not found route. i.e. `path: '**',`

Comment: I have updated my answer. It is needed to put the full absolute path like on the answer.

Comment: Then I can see both components on the same page. i.e. dashboard and barcode. I need 1 component at a time. You can see my update above too.

Comment: Your `dashboard` component has `router-outlet` too?

Comment: Yes, you can see that on the above code. My requirement here is this. I don't need to destroy the dashboard page when it goes to the barcode page.

Comment: It is hard to hide the `dashboard` component html on `barcode` component because dashboard is the parent of barcode. Instead of this, it will be good to create a new component (sth like `DashboardMainComponent`) that contains the `dashboard` component html and set the default route to that component on default routing on dashboard module.

Comment: Please put a small pseudo kind of route config on your answer. I think your approach will work.

Comment: Yes, this is the way. Thanks a lot!